# Kentico ListMenu style

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am using aspx for my template in kentico with a CMSListMenu. The CMSListMenu is like this:

```
        <cms:CMSListMenu CssClass="sm sm-blue" ID="main_menu" Path="/%" 
        runat="server" ClassNames="CMS.MenuItem" />
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
        <ul class="sm sm-blue" ID="main_menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        </ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to ignore the built-in web-parts in Kentico for lists. Rather using the `<cms:CMSRepeater>` and a transformation. The `CMSRepeater` is analogous to asp.net's `<asp:Repeater>` control, with the added access to the Kentico CMS tree structure.

So a deceleration of the `CMSRepeater` in code would look like:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ClassNames="CMS.MenuItem" Path="/%" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="sm sm-blue" id="main_menu">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %></li> <!-- Or whatever column you need to extract for the title-->
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</cms:CMSRepeater>
```

Alternately if you create the `CMSRepeater` web part in the CMS UI, you can set up the list header/footer directly in the dialog, 
and point to a *Transformation* for a *Document Type*. The transformation is a separate file, and will contain the same scope as the content within `<ItemTemplate>` above.